# How to change localization language of c++ extension in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, localization

I'm using Visual studio code with c++ extension and clang compiler to write code on Mac. For some reason spesifically  c++ extension labels are in russian language, for example when i choose which compiler to use or when notification by c++ extension appears. Localization on my mac is fully English and region is Canada, same in VSC.

I tried to reinstall extensions, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason reinstallation of an extension didn't work, but surprisingly when I decided to switch display language of VSC itself to some other one and then back to english - it worked!